# Is there something different with C in Hackerrank(getting different output)?

Tags: c, printf, output, palindrome

I've been trying to do the Love-Letter Mystery Challenge on Hackerrank.
Here are the rules: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery

And here's my solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000

int check_palindrome(char *A)
{
    int i = 0, j;
    while(A[i])
        i++;

    i -= 1;

    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if(A[j] != A[i - j])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int love_letter(char *A)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    int times;
    while(A[i])
        i++;

    i -= 1;

    if(i == 0)
        return 0;

    if(check_palindrome(A))
        return 0;

    for(j = i; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        while(A[j] != 'a')
        {
            if(check_palindrome(A))
                return times;
            else
            {
                A[j] -= 1;
                times += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return times;
}

int main() {

    int t, i;
    char a[MAX];
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", a);
        printf("%d\n", love_letter(a));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While testing in on my computer, I get the right output. But, when I try to run the code on Hackerrank, it tell's that my program always gives an output of:

```
0
0
0
0
```

That's wrong of course, and it fails the testcase. But why is that? Is there something different about C or something? Or is it just a problem with the site? Or with my code?

Comment: I would suggest compiling with more warnings enabled; the uninitialised `times` is easily caught…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a minimum, you seem to have forgotten to initialize the variable "times".

In terms of the actual algorithm, keep in mind that to make the letters match, you can decrement either (or both) of them.  I don't think you handle all cases properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And yes, there are cases I haven't considered, thanks for not revealing everything, I'll get back to work...